# I'm getting the discount %, not the discounted price

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a web scraper with bs4, everything works fine except when the item is on a discount, it outputs the discount %, not the price and I can't figure out how to get the price.

```
elif meno_karty == "8":
    #710
    page_url = "https://www.alza.sk/graficke-karty-s-cipom-nvidia-geforce-gt710/18858832.htm"

    uClient = uReq(page_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"browsingitem"})

    container = containers[0]
    while alwaysTrue == True:
        for container in containers:
            meno = container.div.div.a.img["alt"].replace(" - Grafická karta", "")
            cena = container.find("div",{"class":"priceInner"})
            cas = datetime.now()
            cas_teraz = cas.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print("[" + cas_teraz + "]" + f"{Fore.CYAN} [MENO] {Style.RESET_ALL}" + meno)
            print("[" + cas_teraz + "]" + f"{Fore.GREEN} [CENA] {Style.RESET_ALL}{Fore.RED}" + cena.span.text.replace("Cena nebola stanovená", "X") + Fore.WHITE)
            if "€" in cena.span.text:
                f = open("stock.txt", "a")
                f.write(cas_teraz + " " + meno + " " + cena.span.text + "\n")
                f.close()
                playsound("ding.wav")
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        time.sleep(int(refresh))
```

```
Output:
[10:33:04] [MENO] GAINWARD GT710 2GB DDR3 SilentFX
[10:33:04] [CENA] 57,90 €
[10:33:06] [MENO] ASUS GeForce GT 710 SL-2GD5
[10:33:06] [CENA] 80,90 €
[10:33:08] [MENO] ASUS GeForce GT 710 SL-2GD5-BRK
[10:33:08] [CENA] 81,90 €
[10:33:10] [MENO] GIGABYTE GeForce GT 710 2GB
[10:33:10] [CENA] -9%
```

Comment: Maybe calculate it?

Comment: I probably could do that but that's just unnecessary when I know the price is right there, isn't it?

Comment: So, the question is how to find it on the page?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to find it in the html

Comment: Ok, you need to use your browser. Navigate to the page, fire up developer tools and use "inspect element".

Comment: Yes of course I know that, I just don't know how to get to the exact text, where it displays the price.

Comment: Do you have headers of it for me `page_html` is empty so can you provide it by updating post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the priceInner is as follows

```
<div class="priceInner">
   <div class="npc">
      <span class="np">-9%</span>
      <span class="np2">57,90&nbsp;€</span>
   </div>
   <span class="c2">52,57&nbsp;€</span>
   <span class="c1">bez DPH <b>43,81&nbsp;€</b></span>
</div>
```

So you should just take one extra step and find the span with `class="c2"` inside your `cena` just like you found the div with `class="priceInner"`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure how to do that could you help me?

Comment: Then how did you come up with the example code in the first place? It should be something like:
`cena_c2 = cena.find("span",{"class":"c2"})`

Comment: Oh wow thank you I tried different variations of this a lot of times, no idea why I didn't try this one thank you very much again